# Does ASP.NET Core handle pre-flight requests even without CORS being added as a middleware

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm reading the book *API Security in Action* by Neil Madden. In the book, there is a section about CORS and how to attach the proper headers in Java. I am aware that there is already an `AddCors` and `UseCors` built in to ASP.NET Core, but for my edification I wanted to roll my own middleware.

However, I found that I was unable to receive any sort of `OPTIONS` requests, they were automatically being rejected somehow, and I was unable to respond to them manually, even when it was the first middleware in the pipeline. Since the `UseCors` middleware is able to intercept these pre-flight requests, I'm curious whether or not it is hooking into a deeper level of ASP.NET Core than I am able to.

TL;DR: Is ASP.NET Core (or Kestrel) performing some sort of automatic preflight request checking even when `UseCors` is not called?

Comment: How are you hosting this app? Self host (run via dotnet command)? IIS? IIS Express? Or do you have any other networking component between the browser and your app?

Comment: Kestrel via the `dotnet run` command @mason

Comment: Can you please share a [mcve]?

Comment: @mason I started creating a from-scratch implementation with a simple custom middleware and it worked fine (the request came through and I was able to log it). I then re-added my custom cors middleware to the original application and it worked; I'm not entirely sure why it wasn't working before-hand. I'm still investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the end is no, ASP.NET does not do anything fancy when it comes to preflight requests. I looked into the source code and the `CorsMiddleware` (and associated extensions) are relatively simple; most of the logic is contained within the `ICorsService`, and doesn't impact the middleware pipeline directly.

I'm unsure what my original issue was being caused by, but it is now resolved.

See below for the source code:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsMiddleware.cs

---

It is worth noting that if you add the CORS headers manually, you will get the following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint ProjectName.Controllers.SomeController.Login (ProjectName) contains CORS metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports CORS.
      Configure your application startup by adding app.UseCors() inside the call to Configure(..) in the application startup code. The call to app.UseCors() must appear between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...).
```

You can avoid this error by setting a flag to true in the custom CORS handler

```cs
httpContext.Items["__CorsMiddlewareWithEndpointInvoked"] = true;
```

However, I feel it's important to stress that this should only be done for education purposes; you should be relying on built-in `CorsMiddleware` and not rolling your own whenever possible (and it should hopefully always be possible).